# Изменение текста одного окна при нажатии кнопки с другого

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, pyqt, мультиязычность

Недавно начал учить *Python*, понравилась библиотека *PyQt5*, начал учить. 
В общем проблема следующая - при открытии программы выводится ***окно с выбором языка программы***, например  выбираем *украинский* или *русский* и текст меняется на тот который выбрали.

Пробовал создать функцию и там ввести параметры из главного окна, но не получается.

И еще подскажите пожалуйста как кнопку '*Choose the language*' поставить по центру окна?

**main.py**:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication ,QWidget, QPushButton)
from PyQt5 import QtCore
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
import sys

class MainWindow(QWidget):

  def __init__(self, parent=None):
      super().__init__(parent)
      self.secondWin = None
      self.initUI()


  def initUI(self):
      self.setWindowTitle('Product calculation')
      self.resize(1000, 640)

      qr = self.frameGeometry()
      cp = QtWidgets.QDesktopWidget().availableGeometry().center()
      qr.moveCenter(cp)
      self.move(qr.topLeft())

      self.but = QPushButton(self)
      self.but.setText('Choose the language')
      self.but.resize(120, 30)

      self.but.clicked.connect(self.openCL)
      self.but.clicked.connect(self.hideBut)
      self.but.clicked.connect(self.showbut)
      self.but.move(400, 280)
      self.but.show()

      self.but1 = QPushButton(self)
      self.but1.setText('Create calculation')
      self.but1.resize(140, 32)
      self.but1.move(100, 100)
      self.but1.hide()

      self.but2 = QPushButton(self)
      self.but2.setText('Search a calculation')
      self.but2.resize(140, 32)
      self.but2.move(100, 150)
      self.but2.hide()

      self.but3 = QPushButton(self)
      self.but3.setText('Settings')
      self.but3.resize(140, 32)
      self.but3.move(100, 200)
      self.but3.hide()

      self.but4 = QPushButton(self)
      self.but4.setText('About program')
      self.but4.resize(140, 32)
      self.but4.move(100, 250)
      self.but4.hide()

  def hideBut(self):
      self.but.hide()

  def showbut(self):
      self.but1.show()
      self.but2.show()
      self.but3.show()
      self.but4.show()

  def openCL(self):
      if not self.secondWin:
          self.secondWin = ChooseLang(self)
      self.secondWin.show()

class ChooseLang(QWidget):

  def __init__(self, parent=None):
      super().__init__(parent, QtCore.Qt.Window)

      self.initUI()

  def initUI(self):
      self.setWindowTitle('CL')
      self.resize(200, 100)

      self.butE = QPushButton(self)
      self.butE.setText('English')
      self.butE.move(20, 30)
      self.butE.clicked.connect(self.closeSW)

      self.butIta = QPushButton(self)
      self.butIta.setText('Italian')
      self.butIta.move(20, 60)
      self.butIta.clicked.connect(self.closeSW)

      self.butRu = QPushButton(self)
      self.butRu.setText('Russian')
      self.butRu.move(100, 30)
      self.butRu.clicked.connect(self.closeSW)

      self.butUa = QPushButton(self)
      self.butUa.setText('Ukrainian')
      self.butUa.move(100, 60)
      self.butUa.clicked.connect(self.closeSW)

  def closeSW(self):
      self.close()


if __name__== '__main__':

  app = QApplication(sys.argv)
  window = MainWindow()
  window.show()
  sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PyQt5 - это хороший выбор.

Расположение виджетов в окне правильнее делать используя макеты.
Читайте документы https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlayout.html#details

Чтобы динамически менять языки (переводы) на PyQt5 можно сделать так:

- пишем программу, в которой
  создаем метод, который можно назвать retranslateUi(), и в нем устанавливать тексты, 
  используя translate() вместо tr() (для более подробной информации читайте документы ). 
  http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/i18n.html
  Вызов этого метода при изменении языка для него должен использовать событие changeEvent()
- Затем сформруйте  .ts  (для каждого языка).
  Например, для итальянского выглядит так:

**eng-it.ts**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE TS>
<TS version="2.1" language="it">
<context>
    <name>MainWindow</name>
    <message>
        <location filename="main.py" line="165"/>
        <source>Product calculation</source>
        <translation>Calcolo del prodotto</translation>
    </message>
    <message>
        <location filename="main.py" line="122"/>
        <source>Create calculation</source>
        <translation>Crea calcolo</translation>
    </message>
    <message>
        <location filename="main.py" line="123"/>
        <source>Search a calculation</source>
        <translation>Cerca un calcolo</translation>
    </message>
    <message>
        <location filename="main.py" line="124"/>
        <source>Settings</source>
        <translation>Impostazioni</translation>
    </message>
    <message>
        <location filename="main.py" line="125"/>
        <source>About program</source>
        <translation>Informazioni sul programma</translation>
    </message>
    <message>
        <location filename="main.py" line="120"/>
        <source>Hello, World</source>
        <translation>Ciao, Mondo</translation>
    </message>
</context>
</TS>
```

аналогично и для других языков ...

- Затем сформруйте  .qm:

**lrelease eng-it.ts eng-ru.ts eng-uk.ts**

- Теперь можно запускать приложение:

---

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication ,QWidget, QPushButton,
                             QComboBox, QGridLayout, QLabel)
from PyQt5.QtCore    import QSize, Qt, pyqtSlot, QTranslator, QEvent

class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, chooseLang, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.chooseLang = chooseLang

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.resize(550, 370)

        self.combo = QComboBox()
        self.combo.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.unit_choice)

        self.label = QLabel(alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)

        self.but1 = QPushButton(self, minimumSize=QSize(140, 50))
        self.but2 = QPushButton(self, minimumSize=QSize(140, 50))
        self.but3 = QPushButton(self, minimumSize=QSize(140, 50))
        self.but4 = QPushButton(self, minimumSize=QSize(140, 50))

        self.trans = QTranslator(self)

        self.grid = QGridLayout(self)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.combo, 0, 1, alignment=Qt.AlignRight)
        self.grid.setRowStretch(1, 1)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.label, 2, 0, 1, 2, alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.but1,  3, 0, alignment=Qt.AlignLeft)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.but2,  4, 0, alignment=Qt.AlignLeft)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.but3,  5, 0, alignment=Qt.AlignLeft)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.but4,  6, 0, alignment=Qt.AlignLeft)
        self.grid.setRowStretch(7, 1)

        options = ([('English',   ''), 
                    ('Italian',   'eng-it' ), 
                    ('Russian',   'eng-ru'), 
                    ('Ukrainian', 'eng-uk'),])

        for i, (text, lang) in enumerate(options):
            self.combo.addItem(text)
            self.combo.setItemData(i, lang)
        self.retranslateUi()

    @pyqtSlot(int)
    def unit_choice(self, index):
        data = self.combo.itemData(index)
        if data:
            self.trans.load(data)
            QApplication.instance().installTranslator(self.trans)
        else:
            QApplication.instance().removeTranslator(self.trans)

    def changeEvent(self, event):
        if event.type() == QEvent.LanguageChange:
            self.retranslateUi()
        super(MainWindow, self).changeEvent(event)

    def retranslateUi(self):
        self.setWindowTitle(QApplication.translate('MainWindow', 'Product calculation'))
        self.but1.setText(QApplication.translate('MainWindow',  'Create calculation'))
        self.but2.setText(QApplication.translate('MainWindow',  'Search a calculation'))
        self.but3.setText(QApplication.translate('MainWindow',  'Settings'))
        self.but4.setText(QApplication.translate('MainWindow',  'About program'))
        self.label.setText(QApplication.translate('MainWindow', 'Hello, World'))


ChooseLang = ["English", "Italian", "Russian", "Ukrainian"]

if __name__== '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow(ChooseLang)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]