# Проблемы с перевод приложения на другие языки

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

Хочу сделать динамическую смену языка на pyqt5, сколько не ищу очень мало мануалов, но все они ссылаются на то, что нужен файл перевода с расширением ".ts", я не знаю где его достать или создать. Ищу дальше и вижу, что для его создания можно воспользоваться "lupdate.exe" но нужен файл с расширением ".pro", а тут я вообще не знаю. Помогите пожалуйста с созданием .ts файла

Comment: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/linguist-programmers.html

Comment: GODofZeon скажите пожалуйста отвечает ли что-то на ваш вопрос https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/958515 , https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1132745 , https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1131567

Comment: S. Nick, спасибо большое, ваши ссылки помогли продвинуться дальше))